# Activity Destroyed when trying to call a new Fragment page - Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am using a Xamarin.Android template (BottomNavigationView) to create an app with a bottom menu. I am trying to get it so that one of the pages that is on the menu ie a profile page has a button that will take me to another fragment. However when I call the SupportFragmentManager I am getting an error saying "the activity has been destroyed".

[image]

I'd like both those buttons to go to other pages that also display the bottom menu button (as i would like it to be consistent throughout my app). The code I am using is:

```
FragmentActivity fragmentActivity = new FragmentActivity();
               fragmentActivity.SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction()
               .Replace(Resource.Id.content_frame, ShowFriendRequests.NewInstance())
               .Commit();
```

The template I am using uses the android.support.v4.app.Fragment and has a MainActivity that I think uses FragmentActivity. But I'm not entirely sure because it was all premade. I have just added the fragment files.

Any idea why I'd be getting this error?

Thank you

Comment: Your fragment is attached to `MainActivity`?

Comment: @Yupi stupid question but how would I check that/attach it if not? I'm quite new to fragments! I've been using activities mainly

Comment: Like your `fragemnts` are inside `MainActivity`? You want to replace layout between `toolbar` and `BottomNavigationBar`?

Comment: @Yupi my fragments are just in the fragment folder but get called in the MainActivity. I am trying to call one fragment from another fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyway I think you are not preforming `FragmentTransaction` correctly instead of using `FragmentActivity` use `FragmentTransaction` to replace one `Fragment` with another or to `Add` another `Fragment`. For example in `Java` code that would go like this:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, new ShowFriendRequests()).commit();
```

In c# I suppose something like this:

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTx = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
ShowFriendRequests friendRequest = new ShowFriendRequests();

// Id is ID of your layout which you want to replace with fragment
fragmentTx.Replace(Resource.Id.content_frame, friendRequest);
fragmentTx.Commit();
```